# Unable to connect to SignalR server via Microsoft Edge browser using localhost

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

Angular server is hosted on the local machine.
SignalR server is hosted on a different machine on the network.

When http://192.168.1.2:4200 (IP of local machine) is used via Microsoft Edge browser, I can connect to the hub.

When http://localhost:4200 is used, I am unable to connect and get the following error
"Error during negotiation request"

However both URL works fine on Chrome browser.

I need to build a Cordova windows app which initiates the angular services using http://localhost:4200 
Can anyone help please? I want to use http://localhost:4200 instead of http://192.168.1.2:4200.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Install the cordova build app directly onto the windows device. It will use device IP instead of localhost internally.

Comment: @ Muhammad, From your last post. I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark that solution as an answer for this thread may help other community members in future. Thanks for your understanding.